# /bin/sh^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory error caused by different GIT env configs overriding each other?

Tags: git, shell, sh, lf

A build script I wrote is failing on a ci/cd pipeline (that runs in linux) because somehow the build.sh script got converted/save in CRLF format (based on what i gather online), leading to this error:

```
/bin/sh^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

The script itself is very basic:

```
#!/bin/sh
mvn clean install
```

I want to confirm that the cause is by git due to what i see when running git config. Below details the remedying actions I took:

1. Saving in LF specifically on my IDE (selected line ending shown by Intellij with build.sh open):

[image: file k]

2. Configuring git specifically not to mess with file line endings and converting to CLRF (i got this warning before), so I ran the following commands `git config --global core.autocrlf false`, `git config --global core.eol lf` and recloned the repository.

Here are my git configs (local, global and throughout the system)

Local config:

```
        core.bare=false
        core.logallrefupdates=true
        core.symlinks=false
        core.ignorecase=true
        core.autocrlf=false
```

Global config:

```
http.sslverify=false
core.autocrlf=false
core.eol=lf
```

Running `git config --list --show-origin`:

```
file:"C:\\ProgramData/Git/config"       core.symlinks=false
file:"C:\\ProgramData/Git/config"       core.autocrlf=true
file:"C:\\ProgramData/Git/config"       core.fscache=true
file:C:/Users/testUser/.gitconfig    http.sslverify=false
file:C:/Users/testUser/.gitconfig    core.autocrlf=false
file:C:/Users/testUser/.gitconfig    core.eol=lf
file:.git/config        core.logallrefupdates=true
file:.git/config        core.symlinks=false
file:.git/config        core.ignorecase=true
file:.git/config        core.autocrlf=false
file:.git/config        core.eol=lf
```

I've removed lines that have no relevance to this issue. As you can see in the overall config output, the output show that there's discrepancy in the configs. Could this be causing the issue of my shell script not running properly in other environments?

Comment: Where is the CI/CD? Where is it configured?

Comment: You are using Windows. So `git config --global core.autocrlf false` should be `git config --global core.autocrlf true` (because `^M` is the Windows line ending).

Comment: (the problem is not how it's represented on your machine, the problem is how it's represented in the git repo and subsequently on the CI/CD machine. I didn't read the documentation for these options, but if you get it backward then it's definitely a problem)

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I read the documentation and ran it as true before. git sends this error: "warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in build.sh." Isnt this not what I want? I want to preserve LF in my script since otherwise it'd fail to run in a Linux environment.

Comment: You want linefeed. You don't want carriage return. `/bin/sh^M` indicates you have a carriage return (`^M` is carriage return). I haven't been a heavy Windows user in a while; I switched to mac.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are a few simple rules, although some of them are opinions:

- `core.eol` is not needed; don't bother with it.
- `core.autocrlf` should always be `false`.
- If you have naïve Windows users who will edit `*.sh` files on a Windows system and thereby insert CRLF line endings into them, use `.gitattributes` to correct this.

In the `.gitattributes` file, list the `.sh` files in question, or `*.sh`, along with the directives `text eol=lf`.  List any other files that need special consideration too, while you're at it: `*.jpg` can have a `binary` directive, if you have JPG images in the repository; `*.bat` can be marked `text eol=crlf`; and so on.

This won't fix your existing problem; to do that, clone the repository, check out the bad commit at the tip of the current branch, modify the `.sh` file(s) to replace the existing CRLF line endings with LF-only line endings, and add and commit these files.  (You can do this in the same commit in which you create the `.gitattributes` file.)  If you have a reasonably modern Git, creating the `.gitattributes` file and then running `git add --renormalize build.sh` is supposed to do all of that (except the "create a new commit" step of course) in one fell swoop (or [swell foop](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/one_swell_foop), if you're fond of Spoonerisms).

#### What's going on here?

Line-ending-fiddling in Git is an endless source of confusion.  Part of the problem stems from the fact that people attempt to observe what's happening by inspecting the files in their *working tree*.  That's akin to trying to figure out why the icemaker in your freezer isn't working by taking the trays out and putting them under extremely hot and bright lights, so that the plastic trays melt.  If you do this, you are:

- looking in the wrong place, and
- using a tool that destroys the very information you might be looking for in the first place.

That is, the problem is elsewhere, and by the time you get around to looking for it, it's long gone.

To understand what's going on, and hence how and why anything that fixes the problem actually fixes the problem, you must first learn the Three Places Of Git where files can be found:

- Files are stored, permanently<sup>1</sup> and immutably, inside commits, in a special, read-only, Git-only, compressed and de-duplicated form.  Each commit acts as an archive—kind of like a tar or zip archive—of *every* file as of the state that file had at the time you committed it.

  Because of the special properties of these files, they literally cannot be used by your computer, except by Git itself.  They must therefore be *extracted*, like un-archiving an archive with `tar -x` or `unzip`.
- Files are stored in a *usable* form, as everyday files, in your working tree.  This is where the extracted (unzipped, or whatever) files wind up.  These files are *not actually in Git at all*.  They are there for you to use as inputs and/or outputs, and your working tree is just an ordinary set of folders (or directories, whichever term you prefer) and files, stored in the way that is ordinary for your particular computer.<sup>2</sup>

That covers two places: so where is this "third place" I talk about?  This is what Git calls, variously, the *index*, or the *staging area*, or—rarely these days—the *cache*.  Git's index holds a *third "copy" of every file*.  I put the word "copy" in quotes here because what's in the index is actually a sort of reference, using the de-duplication trick.

Initially, when you first use `git checkout` or `git switch` to extract a particular commit from a repository you've just cloned, what Git does is:

- "copy" each file into its own index: this "copy" is in the read-only Git-only compressed-and-de-duplicated form; then
- expand the file into usable form and put that into your working tree.

Note that before this step, Git's index was *empty:* it had no files in it at all.  Now Git's index has *every file from the current commit*.  These take no space, because they're de-duplicated and—having come *out of a commit*—they're all already *in the repository* so they *are duplicates* and therefore these copies use no space to hold the data.<sup>3</sup>

So: what's the *point* of this index / staging-area / cache?  Well, one point is that it makes Git go fast.  Another is that it lets you *partially stage* files (though I won't cover what that means here).  But in fact, it's not strictly necessary: other version control systems get away without having one.  It's just that Git not only *has* it, Git *forces you to use it*.  So you need to know about it, if only to know that it places itself between you and your files—in your working tree—and the commits in the repository.

By omitting a few details that eventually matter, but not yet, we can describe the index pretty well as your *proposed next commit*.  That is, the index holds *each file that will go into the **next** commit*.  These files are in Git's own format—compressed and de-duplicated—but, unlike the files inside a *commit*, you *can* **replace** them.  You can't *modify* them (they're in the read-only format, and pre-de-duplicated), but you can run `git add`.

The `git add` command *reads the working tree copy of some file*.  This working tree copy is the version you see and work with.  If you've *changed* it, `git add` reads the changed version.<sup>4</sup>  The `add` command compresses this data down into Git's special internal format and checks to see if it's a duplicate.  If it *is* a duplicate, Git throws out its compression result and re-uses the existing data, updating the index with the re-used file.  If it's *not* a duplicate, Git saves the compressed and de-duplicated (but first time now) file data and updates the index with *that*.

**Either way, what's in the index now is the updated file.**  So the index now holds your proposed next commit.  It held your proposed next commit *before* the `git add` too, but now your proposed next commit is updated.  This tells us what the index is for from *our* point of view: **The index holds your proposed next commit.  You do not commit what is in your working tree.  Instead, you commit what is in Git's index.  This is why you need to know about the index: it's how Git makes new commits.**

---

<sup>1</sup>The commits themselves are only permanent until you or Git remove them, but in a lot of cases that's "never".  It's actually kind of hard to get rid of a Git commit, for many reasons.  A file's data as stored *in* a commit, de-duplicated, remains in the repository until *every* commit that holds that file is removed, though.

<sup>2</sup>The actual file storage format inside computers is itself amazingly complicated and varied.  Some systems do case-preserving but case-folding in file *names*, for instance, so that `README.md` and `ReadMe.md` are "the same file", while others say that these are two *different* files.  Git holds the latter opinion, and when the commit archive holds both a `README.md` *and* a `ReadMe.md`, and you extract that commit to your working tree, *one* of those files goes missing from your working tree, since it's physically incapable of holding both (because they have the "same name" as far as *your* computer is concerned).  Because Git's archived files are in a special Git-only *format*, this is not a problem for *Git itself*.  But it can be a huge headache for *you*.

<sup>3</sup>The other properties stored in the index—such as the cache aspect, which helps Git go fast—do take a bit of space.  The average tends to somewhere close to 100 bytes per file, so unless you have a million files (which then needs ~100 MB of index), this is utterly trivial in modern systems where a chip the size of your fingernail provides 256 GB of storage.

<sup>4</sup>If you *haven't* changed it, `git add` tries to *skip* reading it, to make Git go fast.  This will cause us problems in a moment.  So sometimes you may find it useful to trick Git into *thinking* you've changed it.  You can do this by rewriting the file in place, or using the `touch` command if you have that, for instance.  The `--renormalize` flag to `git add` is *supposed* to fix this as well, but I have seen people say it doesn't.

---

#### How this relates to line endings

Let's review quickly now:

- Every commit contains files-as-a-snapshot, in a frozen (read-only), compressed, de-duplicated format.  Nothing, not even Git itself, can ever *change* any part of any commit.
- Git makes *new* commits from whatever is in Git's index.  Git fills in the index *from* a commit when you check out the commit, and builds the *new* commit from whatever is in its index at the time you run `git commit`.
- Your working tree lets you see what *came out of a commit:* the files come out of the commit, go into Git's index, and then get copied *and expanded* to become ordinary files in your working tree.  Your working tree lets you *control what goes into a new commit:* you run `git add` and the data get compressed, de-duplicated, and generally Git-ified and put *into* the index, ready to be committed.

Note that there are steps here where Git does something *very easy* for Git: copying a commit into the index doesn't *change* any of the files at all, as they're still in the special read-only, Git-only format.  Making a new commit doesn't *change* any of the files at all: they just get packaged up into a (read-only) commit, from the (replaceable but still read-only) "copies" in the index.  But there are two steps where Git does something much harder:

- As a file gets copied *out of the index to your working tree*, it gets expanded and transformed.  Git has to change from compressed bytes to uncompressed bytes.  **This is an ideal time to change LF-only to CRLF** and this is when Git will do that, *if* Git does it at all.
- As a file gets copied *from the working tree* to be compressed and Git-ified and checked if it's a duplicate, Git has to change from uncompressed bytes to compressed ones.  **This is an ideal time to change CRLF to LF-only** and this is when Git will do that, *if* Git does it at all.

So it's copies in and out of the index where Git does CRLF line ending modification.  Moreover, the "index -> working tree" step—which happens during `git checkout`, for instance—can only *add* CRs.  It can't *remove* them.  The "working tree -> index" step—which happens during `git add`, for instance—can only *remove* CRs, not add them.

This in turn means that, if you choose to start doing line ending transformation, the *committed files inside the repository* will eventually end up with LF-only line endings, over time.  If some committed files have CRLF line endings now, they will, in *those commits*, have those endings forever, because no *existing* commit can be changed.

#### Optimizations that get in the way

Now we get to some of the optimizations:

- When checking out a commit, Git tries hard *not* to touch the working tree if possible.  This is slow!  Let's not do it if we don't have to.
- When using `git add`, Git tries hard *not* to touch the index if possible.  It's too slow!

Suppose you check out some commit, say, `deadbeef`.  It has 5923 files in it.  Those files get "copied" into the index, which is really fast because these aren't real copies.  But were there files in the index before?  Say you had commit `dadc0ffee` out just before you switched to `deadbeef`.  *That* commit had put 5752 files in the index, and then all you did was look at the working tree copies.

Obviously these files aren't *all* the same, but what if 5519 of the files were the same, leaving only 233 files to *change* and 171 new files to *create*.  For whatever reason, there are no files in `dadc0ffee` that *aren't* in `deadbeef`, there are only new files.  Or maybe one file does go away and Git will have to remove that one from the working tree and create 172 files.  But either way, Git only needs to *mess with* 404 or 405 files in the working tree, not more than 5500.  That's going to run about ten times faster.

So, Git *does that*.  If Git can, it *doesn't touch files*.  It *assumes* that if file `path/to/file.ext` in the index in commit `dadc0ffee` has the same raw hash ID as file `path/to/file.ext` in the index in commit `deadbeef`, it does not have to do anything to the working tree copy.

This assumption breaks down in the presence of CRLF line ending trickiness.  If Git is *supposed to* do LF to CRLF modifications on the way out, but didn't for `dadc0ffee`, Git may skip doing it for `deadbeef` too.

What this means is that whenever you *change* the CRLF line endings settings, you can end up with "wrong" line endings in your working tree.  You can get around this by *removing the working tree copy* and then checking out the file again (with `git restore` or `git reset --hard`, for instance, though remember that `git reset --hard` loses uncommitted work!).

Meanwhile, if you run `git add` on some file, and Git *thinks* that the cached index copy is up to date—because you haven't edited the working tree copy, for instance—Git will silently do nothing at all.  But if the working tree copy has CRLF line endings, and the index (and hence future commit) copy shouldn't, this is wrong.  Using `git add --renormalize` is supposed to get around it, or you can "touch" the file so that Git sees a newer working-tree time stamp and will redo the copy.  Or, you can even run `git rm --cached` on the file, and then `git add` really does have to copy it, because there's no longer a copy of *that* file in the index at all.

#### Summary: the reason for the "simple rules" above

Using a `.gitattributes` file entry gives Git the most chance to get things right: Git can tell if the `.gitattributes` file entry affects some particular file.  That gives Git the opportunity to do better cache checking, for instance.  (Git currently doesn't *use* this opportunity properly, I think, but at least it offers the possibility.)

When you do use `.gitattributes` entries, they tell Git multiple things:

- this file definitely *is* or *isn't* text: do, or don't, mess with it;
- if you *are* going to mess with line endings, here's what to do.

This lets you say that `*.bat` files need to be CRLF-ended in the working tree, even on a Linux system, and `*.sh` files need to be LF-ended in the working tree, even on a Windows system.

You get as much control as Git is willing to give you:

- You get the ability to turn CRLF in the working tree into LF-only in the index and hence in *future* commits.
- You get the ability to turn LF-only in *committed copies of files* into CRLF in the working tree, on future *extractions* of *this* commit.

The one thing you lose is the easy and global effect of `core.eol` and `core.autocrlf`: these affect existing commits, and tell Git to *guess* whether each file is text.  As long as Git guesses right, that tends to work sort-of-OK.  It's when Git guesses *wrong* that things go really bad.  But because these settings affect every file extraction (index-to-work-tree) and every `git add` (work-tree-to-index) *that actually happens*, and it's hard to know which ones *happen*, it's very hard to see what's going on.

Comment: I have to commend this is an underrated answer and thank you for writing something so comprehensive

Answer (score 1):

```
git config --global core.autocrlf false

git rm --cached -r .

git reset --hard
```

This is just for the ones who are lazy... like me